# Class With Non-Optional Property Conforming To Protocol With Optional Property

Tags: swift

If I have a protocol that has an optional property, and a class that needs to conform to the protocol which has the same property already, but as a non-optional property, how do I make the class conform to the protocol.

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var a: String? { get set }
}

class MyClass {
    var a: String
}

extension MyClass: MyProtocol {
    // What do I put here to make the class conform
}
```

Comment: In some sense, when _reading_ `a`, `MyClass` satisfies a stronger postcondition than the protocol requires. Except if `a` is required writable then `MyClass` fails, since it also strengthens the precondition - the protocol requires the optionality. But if the protocol stated `a` as `get` only, then is it true that a non-optional implementation of `a` could indeed conform? (Tested it doesn't)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't redeclare the same variable in `MyClass` with a different type.

What Dennis suggests will work, but if you want to keep your variable in `MyClass` non-Optional, then you could use a computed property to wrap around your stored variable:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var a: String? { get set }
}

class MyClass {
    // Must use a different identifier than 'a'
    // Otherwise, "Invalid redeclaration of 'a'" error
    var b: String
}

extension MyClass: MyProtocol {
    var a: String? {
        get {
            return b
        }
        set {
            if let newValue = newValue {
                b = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ronald. This is what I was trying to do, I was just hoping that there was a different way so that I didn't have to have a different name for the variable in my class than in the protocol to use a computed property.

Comment: No problem. It may help to consider why having the same identifier won't work: if `a` can either be a `String` or a `String?`, the compiler won't be able to infer the correct type of `a` whenever it is referenced. This breaks type-safety and makes it more difficult to reason about your code.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense to me. I just was hoping that there was a language feature that I wasn't aware of that got around this. Thanks again.

Comment: @RonaldMartin it makes sense why it can't be non-optional, but it seems like it should be able to be a force-unwrapped optional— since the underlying type is optional, but just with a runtime check for non-optionality. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be allowed…

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make the property of the class optional as well in order to conform to the protocol, as follows:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var a: String? { get set }
}

class MyClass {
    var a: String? // Added '?'
}

extension MyClass: MyProtocol {
    // Nothing needed here to conform
}
```

Comment: That's a terrible solution