# Type cannot conform to a protocol with a member that has the same name but is optional

Tags: swift

I have a struct with a member named `email` of type `String`, and a protocol with a member named `email` of type `String?`.  I would think it should be trivial to have the struct conform to that protocol, since it has the necessary information, but I'm being blocked by the compiler.  Here's a pared down example I put together in a playground:

```swift
struct SimpleStruct {
    let email: String
}

protocol SimpleProtocol {
    var email: String? { get }
}

// Type 'SimpleStruct' does not conform to protocol 'SimpleProtocol'
extension SimpleStruct: SimpleProtocol {}
```

The error specifically says:

> Candidate has non-matching type 'String'

It also offers a fix:

> Do you want to add protocol stubs?

But unsurprisingly that leads to a redeclaration error.

```swift
extension SimpleStruct: SimpleProtocol {
    var email: String? {
        // Invalid redeclaration of 'email'
    }
}
```

I understand that `String` and `Optional<String>` are different types, but I would expect that simply saying `SimpleStruct` conforms to `SimpleProtocol` with no additional code should compile, for the same reason that I can pass a string to a function that expects an optional string.  Can someone explain why I'm mistaken?

Note: I realize I can get around this issue in a number of ways, most notably just renaming the `email` field in `SimpleProtocol`.  But I'd like to understand why this is necessary as well as know if there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: answer to the same question https://stackoverflow.com/a/33113757/5397625

Comment: This is essentially the same limitation as in [Why can't a get-only property requirement in a protocol be satisfied by a property which conforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42561685/2976878), except instead of a get-only property requirement of protocol type being satisfied by a property of a conforming type, you're looking for a more general subtyping relationship. There's no technical reason why it's not possible, it just hasn't been implemented yet (though unfortunately an implementation now would come with source compatibility concerns).

Comment: @Hamish thanks for linking to that question, I appreciate the detail you went into in your answer there!

Comment: I would say the surprise is the other way. The fact that given an Optional wrapping a String, it is legal to assign a String directly to it, is just weird. You’ve gotten used to it, but it is based on some bizarre mechanism baked into the language. After all you can’t  assign a String where a `Wrapper<String>` is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, `String` and `String?` are not the same type, you simply can't conform to a protocol if your types don't match.

Picture what would happen if the protocol declared the variable like this `{ get set }` and another object tried to assign a `nil` value. It would crash because your type is not actually honoring the protocol.

What you could do is to create another variable that's not optional and store the value there, and implement `email` like this:

`var email: String? { return emailValue }`

This way you have the non optional you want but still conform to the protocol. But doing exactly what you want is not possible.